# javascript regular expression match

Tags: javascript, regex, match

I need to split a string like the one below, based on space as the delimiter. But any space within a quote should be preserved. There are two cases which needs to work

### Case 1

```
research library "not available" author:"Bernard Shaw"
```

to

```
research 
library 
"not available" 
author:"Bernard Shaw"
```

### Case 2

```
research library "not available" author:Bernard
```

to

```
research 
library 
"not available" 
author:Bernard
```

I am trying to do this with Javascript and regular expression.

```
var splitArray = query_string.match(/([^\s]*\"[^\"]+\")|\w+/g);
```

Case 1 works as required but Case 2 produces the result as below

```
research 
library 
"not available" 
author
Bernard
```

I need both the cases to work with one Regex. Any ideas appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[^"\s]+(?:"[^"]+")?|"[^"]+"
```

Explanation:

```
[^"\s]+       # One or more non-space/non-quote characters
(?:"[^"]+")?  # optionally followed by a quoted string
|             # or
"[^"]+"       # just a quoted string.
```

Assuming that there are no escaped quotes within quoted strings.

Comment: Thanks Tim. It works great. Looks to me the most comprehensive of all the answers.

Answer (score 1):

```
([^\s]*\"[^\"]+\")|\w+:?
```

I've tested this regex here: [rubular](http://www.rubular.com/r/YR7TqO4X2W)

update: 
you may want to include some more punctuation marks like `;` `,` `.` `?` `!`
*e.g. research library! "not available" author:"Bernard Shaw" test1, test2; test2!*

```
([^\s]*\"[^\"]+\")|\w+[:;\.,\?!]?
```

Comment: thanks. it gives "author:" and "Bernard" separately when I try to put it in use. In Rubular, seems to work well though.

Answer (score 0):

This works, at least for your two cases:

```
((?:[^\s]*\"[^\"]+\")|[\w:]+)
```

[see here](http://www.rubular.com/r/orkOTCNypT)